# capitalize multiple examples of acronyms found in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

Acronyms such as cnv, fha, rhs, va, etc. are found in a string column in Oracle SQL developer and need to be capitalized. These acronyms are mixed in with other text that should remain un-capitalized. Need to have some kind of combination of PL/SQL functions that find & capitalize these acronyms.

Functions like `REGEXP_REPLACE`, `REGEXP_LIKE` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` seem to be functions that may do this. Just haven't figured out the right combination of functions to use.

Tried this, is there a way to insert an UPPER function in place of the 'FHA' portion of this code below that capitalizes the 'cnv|fha|rhs|va' instead of replacing all of them with 'FHA'?

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Bank of Nowhere - fha', 'cnv|fha|rhs|va', 'FHA', 1, 1,'i') as test_1
FROM dual;
```

There are other string examples like the one listed above such as 'Bank of Nowhere - cnv' or 'Bank of Nowhere - va', etc.

Comment: You would need to create a registry of known acronyms, probably best kept in a table, and then use that to drive your REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: You may also need to avoid replacing the pattern inside a word by using a "whole word" matching criteria: 
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Bank of Nowhere - fha', '(^|\W|\s)(cnv|fha|rhs|va)($|\W|\s)', '\1FHA\3', 1, 1, 'i') as test_1
FROM dual;